# How do I get to the answer that is given using normal differentiation and standard rules of exponents?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given that  $y = \dfrac{x^3 - 5x}{\sqrt{x}}$, show that $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$= $\dfrac{5(x^2 - 1)} {2 \sqrt{x}} $  using standard rules of exponents.

I get as far as  $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac {5}{2}x^\frac {3}{2}  - \dfrac {5}{2}x^\frac{-1}{2}$  but struggling with the first fraction to make a common denominator and thus get to the answer.

Comment: Didn't you just post this somewhere else?

Comment: It did but it got very clogged up with correct answers that i wasn't looking for. I am new so apologies. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: @Andros "correct answers that i wasn't looking for" just doesn't make sense!

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Sorry! I'm going through a textbook so using methods that have just been taught. Your help was much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dfrac{5(x^2-1)}{2\sqrt{x}} = \dfrac{5}{2}\cdot \left(\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x}} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right) = \dfrac{5}{2}\left(x^{\frac{3}{2}} - x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

$x^{3/2}=x^{1/2}x$ and $x^{-1/2}=x/x^{1/2}$, and so, $$x^{3/2}-x^{1/2}=x(x^{1/2}+\dfrac{1}{x^{1/2}})=x(\dfrac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}})=\sqrt{x}(x+1)$$